# R: how to get the character representation of a ScaleDiscrete object derived from a scale_fill_manual() call to resolve correctly in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

data set for my question:

```
set.seed(1)
dfr2 <- tibble(x1 = factor(sample(letters[1:3], 50, replace = T), levels=letters[1:3]),
             x2 = factor(sample(letters[1:2], 50, replace = T), levels=letters[1:2]),
             x3 = factor(sample(letters[1:3], 50, replace = T), levels=letters[1:3]),
             grpA = factor(sample(c("grp1","grp2"),50, prob=c(0.3, 0.7) ,replace=T), levels = c("grp1", "grp2")),
             grpB = factor(sample(c("grp1","grp2"),50, prob=c(0.6, 0.4) ,replace=T), levels = c("grp1", "grp2"))
             )

head(dfr2)
```

function to prepare my data for plotting:

```
plot_data_prepr <- function(dat, groupvar, mainvar){
  
  groupvar <- sym(groupvar)
  mainvar <- sym(mainvar)
  
  plot_data <- dat %>% 
    group_by(!!groupvar) %>% 
    count(!!mainvar, .drop = F) %>% drop_na() %>% 
    mutate(pct = n/sum(n),
         pct2 = ifelse(n == 0, 0.005, n/sum(n)),
         grp_tot = sum(n),
         pct_lab = paste0(format(pct*100, digits = 1),'%'),
         pct_pos = pct2 + .02)
  
  return(plot_data)
}
```

normal usage of data prep function:

```
plot_data_prepr(dat = dfr2, groupvar = "grpA", mainvar = "x1")
```

creating custom color scales for the 3-level factors ("x1", "x3") and 2-level factor ("x2"):

```
factor_3lev <- levels(dfr2$x1)

factor_3lev_col <- c(brewer.pal(11,"RdBu")[c(2,7,9)])
names(factor_3lev_col) <- factor_3lev
factor_3lev_col_scale <- scale_fill_manual(values=factor_3lev_col)
show_col(factor_3lev_col)

factor_2lev <- levels(dfr2$x2)

factor_2lev_col <- c(brewer.pal(11,"RdBu")[c(2,7)])
names(factor_2lev_col) <- factor_2lev
factor_2lev_col_scale <- scale_fill_manual(values=factor_2lev_col)
show_col(factor_2lev_col)
```

assigning the custom color scale names to the name 'col_scales2':

```
col_scales2 <- grep("factor.*_col_scale", ls(), value = T)
```

calling the class() function on the color scale names reveals that color scales are ScaleDiscrete objects:

```
class(factor_3lev_col_scale)
class(factor_2lev_col_scale)
```

calling the class function on the string representation of the color scales reveals that these objects are character objects:

```
class(col_scales2[1])
class(col_scales2[2])
```

it then follows that these are not identical:

```
identical(factor_3lev_col_scale, col_scales2[1])
identical(factor_2lev_col_scale, col_scales2[2])
```

and that when I try assign the string representation of the custom color scale to 'col_scal' and then subsequently use 'col_scal' with ggplot2::ggplot(), it fails:

```
for(gvar in names(dfr2)[4]){
  for(mvar in names(dfr2)[1:3])  {
    
    if (mvar %in% names(dfr2[c(1,3)])) {
      col_scal <- col_scales2[1]
    } else {
      col_scal <- col_scales2[2]
    }   
    print(ggplot(plot_data_prepr(dfr2, gvar, mvar),
                 aes(x = !!sym(mvar), y = pct2, fill = !!sym(mvar))) +
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
      ylim(0,1) +
      geom_text(aes(label=pct_lab, y = pct_pos + .02)) +
      col_scal +  
      facet_grid(as.formula(paste0(".~", gvar))) +
      ggtitle(paste0(mvar, " by ", gvar)))
  }
}
```

but that when I assign the actual name of the custom color scale to 'col_scal' and then subsequently use 'col_scal' with ggplot2::ggplot(), it works:

```
for(gvar in names(dfr2)[4]){
  for(mvar in names(dfr2)[1:3])  {
    
    if (mvar %in% names(dfr2[c(1,3)])) {
      col_scal <- factor_3lev_col_scale
    } else {
      col_scal <- factor_2lev_col_scale
    }   
    print(ggplot(plot_data_prepr(dfr2, gvar, mvar),
                 aes(x = !!sym(mvar), y = pct2, fill = !!sym(mvar))) +
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
      ylim(0,1) +
      geom_text(aes(label=pct_lab, y = pct_pos + .02)) +
      col_scal +  
      facet_grid(as.formula(paste0(".~", gvar))) +
      ggtitle(paste0(mvar, " by ", gvar)))
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the character representation of the color scales to resolve correctly to a ScaleDiscrete object so that I may use it in ggplot? I want to do this so I can dynamically select color scales from a vector of color scale names (like 'col_scales2') and choose a color scale based on the factor that is selected for the 'mainvar' argument in the plot_data_prepr() function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this.  It works fine.

```
if (mvar %in% names(dfr2[c(1,3)])) {
      col_scal <- eval_tidy(as.name(col_scales2[2]))
    } else {
      col_scal <- eval_tidy(as.name(col_scales2[1]))
    }
```

You get the following output:

[image: output]